# Are non-final static strings more efficient than static final strings?

Tags: java, java-me

I just read an article in the BlackBerry docs about [writing efficient code in J2ME](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/9095/BP_Writing_efficient_code_446999_11.jsp).

In that article there is a section that advises you to "use static variables for Strings."  The reasoning is that, since the compiler inlines `static final` references as string literals, it's better to leave it non-final (I guess the assumption is that retrieving a static reference is cheaper than retrieving from the string pool?).

Is this true for all JVMs??  My boss at my last job pounded it into our heads that we should always, *always* use `static final` for our constants.  We were doing embedded programming in Java, so he was a real stickler for performance (although I'm not sure in this case whether he was more concerned with memory or speed).  My boss has been doing Java for years and really knows his stuff, so I took his advice; now I'm getting contradictory advice!

So which one is really better?  You can answer from either a memory conservation perspective or a speed perspective, and for either J2ME or J2SE.

Comment: You should probably use static final. Let the machine do what it does to determine if something should be inlined. Also if you're worried about the performance of inlining a string versus calling it, java probably isn't the right language to be working in

Comment: When you're programming UI for Android or BlackBerry, you don't have a choice of languages.  But beyond that, it's _always_ better to know what's going on under the hood!  C'mon, man, it's a matter of principle!  You don't obey the machines, the machines obey you!  Also, why is this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: True that you don't have a choice in things like android, but then inlining strings is BY FAR not the bottleneck, it's the 60 other applications running in the background that are. Also, sure it's better to know what's going on under the hood, but with languages like java, you really can't since it's up to the virtual machine to do with the code what it wants.

Comment: Well then the answer is, "This will vary across JVMs.  There is no concrete way to know which is better."  Still, I'm not so sure.  String interning is a pretty basic part of any JVM implementation so I feel that if we know what works best on one JVM, that will probably apply to all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, they should be the same.  (With *the same* defined as close enough that it will never ever matter)

I would very strongly argue that you should encode your intent (i.e. having the static vs non-static-ness defined by whether this is a **class** constant versus an **instance** constant) rather than some arbitrary "performance enhancement"

If you find that this is a significant performance problem (and only AFTER you measure it!), I would classify it as a compiler / JVM defect and put the workaround (Swapping its static-ness) in place, with a comment indicating why.

Comment: I'm not swapping static-ness, I'm swapping finality.  And I would normally agree with you that the difference is negligible, but on the other hand we've got this fellow from RIM saying that it's not.  You have 7000+ points on SO, but this guy is possibly a co-author of the VM itself.  Who should I believe?

Comment: Answer:  I should believe the benchmark and _only_ the benchmark.  Yes, I know.  But this isn't about a specific performance gain.  This is about choosing a programming style which my whole team can use going forward.  I shouldn't have to run benchmarks if I can weigh the pros and cons of both methods and pick one based on that...

Comment: @Neil Traft: You shouldn't judge my answer based on my rep :)  That said, it's really easy to make performance enhancements based on out of date information.  When the next release comes by and fixes their compiler / VM slowness, maybe the performance gain will flip!  You never know.  That's why I say you should measure it to see if it's too slow before even thinking about it.